# Is it possible to base a SSRS report variable on the deployment configuration?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm generating an image dynamically based on a report parameter value, but the URL for that image depends on the environment. Is it possible to set a variable value to different things based on the deployment configuration used to deploy the report, similar to the web.config transforms?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a SQL query to return @SERVERNAME and use that information to select the correct URL for the image.